# numericUpDown ValueChanged after MouseLeftButtonDown

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I have 2 controls on a form.  One ***numericUpDown*** (from the Silverlight Toolkit) and a simple ***Rectangle***.

On the ***MouseLeftButtonDown*** of the Rectangle I popup a MessageBox with the numericUpDown value.

If I use the arrows to change the value of the numericUpDown, everyting is fine.  But if I edit the value manually (with the keyboard) and immediately click on the Rectangle it shows the previous value of the numericUpDown.  If I click a sencond time on the rectangle it will show the new value.

The ***numericUpDown.ValueChanged*** event is raised after the ***Rectangle.MouseLeftButtonDown*** event.

Is that a Silverlight bug?  Anybody knows a workaround for that?

(btw I cannot change my Rectangle controls or events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As workaround I propose you to create your own control like:

```
public class MyNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
    {
        private TextBox _textBox;
        public void Sync()
        {
            ApplyValue(_textBox.Text);
        }
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            _textBox = (TextBox)GetTemplateChild("Text");
        }
    }
```

Now you can use method Sync to syncronize display text with control Value property. You can call method from XAML declaratively or in code behind. In your case:

```
private void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            myNumericUpDown.Sync();
            MessageBox.Show(myNumericUpDown.Value.ToString());
        }
```